# CSS / Style Heading Tags

Tags: css, css-selectors

I tried many css from other places and stackoverflow, but somehow I can not make it done.

I'm very new to css, and using Joomla and a template. I'm using custom.css folder for certain customizations on style. Here is I want to do:

I want to style h5 when it is a link.

For example, I'm creating a custom html module, have a list in the content. And in the content I'm giving each, h5 style, and a link to it to a certain page in the site.

What I want to achieve is to have this list with color blue. And when mouse over-hover to have underline and still the same color. And when clicked back to the original position with no underline and no color change. (the same color in every situation, just underline when you are over it.)

I tried these h5, h5 a, h5 a: hover, h5 .contentheading a, and so on...

In one instance, it was working with :

```
h5 {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.3em;
  font-weight: bold;
}

h5 a {
  color: #0088CC;
}

h5 a: hover {
  color: #0088CC;
  text-decoration: underline; 
}
```

As I read I should use 'a' when the heading is a link.

But now something is overriding it, I'm completely lost now.

I see a:hover style in the inspection.

I want to use this h5 in several content (in custom modules) when I want to style a content as a list to links. And I thought it will be practical to have one heading with a certain style so that I can use it with flexibility.

Thanks a lot, any help will be great : )

Comment: Don't forget to mark an appropriate answer as "correct".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like you have a space betwen `a:` and `hover`. Try:

```
h5 {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.3em;
  font-weight: bold;
}

h5 a {
  color: #0088CC;
}

h5 a:hover {
  color: #0088CC;
  text-decoration: underline; 
}
```

Comment: I can't believe spending hours on a space ! Thank you very much, it is working fine.

Comment: @OP, you are far from the first developer to have done such a thing.

Comment: Oops I spent too much time writing the answer.

Answer (score 2):

As it was already pointed out by [JSK NS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12919810/772323), there should be no space between `a:` and `hover`. And if you want the link to be underlined only on mouse hover, you should add

`text-decoration: none`

in the `h5 a` section. You can also remove the repeating color in `h5 a:hover` as it is redundant. Final CSS would be like so :

```
h5 {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.3em;
  font-weight: bold;
}

h5 a {
  color: #0088CC;
  text-decoration: none;
}

h5 a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline; 
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I don't know when to put space or not to put, I thought we are putting space after ':' like in color...

Comment: Yes, it looks like redundant, but I have in my original template theme css, hover style and colors for a larger class, so I think it overrides it because when I remove it, the hover color goes back to some other color I did not specify.

Answer (score 1):

There is an error in your syntax. Space between a:hover, this should be written as one.

```
h5 {
    font-family: arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 1.3em;
    font-weight: bold;
}

h5 a {
    color: #0088CC;
}

h5 a:hover {
    color: #0088CC;
    text-decoration: underline; 
}
```

Comment: CSS does not support nesting. Maybe you're using some preprocessor like LESS?

Comment: Your entire code sample is a syntax error. As mentioned, CSS does not support nesting at all.

Comment: Thanks! Does spacing before each line makes any difference on the code, or I should not be asking this question !

Comment: BoltClock I'm a bit confused, which code are we talking about with the syntax error?

Comment: @BoltClock and xec : sorry to misguide.I really got it wrong. Edited it back.

Comment: @user1750613 You cannot nest like what i told.you can group them.If you have to apply h2 and h3 same styles.You may group them.I got it wrong. If you dont know what I mean you may check it here http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_grouping_nesting.asp

Comment: @user1750613 No spacing won't effect. But you cant have a space between a:hover because they have to be together. Its like you write a:hover like a : h o v e r and ask what's wrong.